# I'm trying to trigger the HTML5 color picker's popup with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When an input[type=color] is clicked, a color picker opens in a popup window.  I'd like to trigger this with JS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="customColorPick"></div>
<input id="customColorPickInput" type="color" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#customColorPick").click(function() {
    $("#customColorPickInput").click();
});
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: There is no way to trigger it without a click occurring somewhere in the DOM. You can try hiding it, and then having text: https://jsfiddle.net/qe28xx1x/ (<- click on *Color*).

Comment: I just have created a fiddler and it works for both Chrome and Firefox.https://jsfiddle.net/tgptaezr/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it might not be what you are looking for but it might work for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/htmlcssperson/qe28xx1x/4/
Click on the box with a color inside

```
<div id="color">
  <div class="colorpick">
    <input id="customColorPicker" type="color" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.colorpick {
  visibility: shown;
}
```